# Chrome extension content scripts: wait for variable

Tags: javascript, http, google-chrome-extension

So I'm working on a Chrome extension and I want to send a variable over to the content script. However, the variable can only be obtained using XMLHTTP requests and doesn't arrive immediately. Also, the content script executes when a tab loads. Is there any way to wait for a variable to become anything but null before executing the content script? Thanks.

Comment: Question, why can't the content script load it? We need more details.

Comment: The http request will only go through if sent directly from the main script as the content script doesn't have the right permissions as it needs to be logged into the account on the site the data is being retrieved from. Not sure if that made any sense or not, please tell me if I'm not.

Comment: So far it doesn't make that much sense. Cookies are shared, cross-origin permissions as well.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are sending ajax call in background page.

1. Use [Programmatic injection](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#pi) instead of including the content scripts in `manifest.json`. You could call `chrome.tabs.executeScript` inside your ajax callback.
2. Or you can use [Message Passing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) to communicate between content script and background page. Wrap your original content script logic as a function and only call it when receiving message from background page, while background page would send message to content scripts once ajax call succeeds.